# Reusing a list in a new function

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I have a function, which among many things, appends items to a list "machines_off". What I need to do now is reference that list in another function and then run actions on each item in that list.

How do I reference the list from the first function? Obviously at the moment it complains that the list name is not defined...

Thanks again!

Comment: how about returning that list and passing it to the other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure exactly what you are asking as it is a little vague but I think this should be what you are trying to do.

```
func_2(myList)
```

Now the list has been returned you can send it over to the second function

```
func_2(myList)
*do some stuff to the list*
```

And a full working example

```
def f1(mList):
    mList.append('BLAH' + str(len(mList)))
    f2(mList)

def f2(mList):
    for item in mList:
        print ('Printing from f2')
        print (item)
    print()

myList = []
f1(myList)
f1(myList)
f1(myList)

for item in myList:
    print ('Printing from MAIN')
    print (item)
```

Comment: Thanks @Modred for the reply. Should I put the first line within func_1 or outside it? If I put it inside, it errors, saying 'func_1(myList) takes no arguments, 1 given'. If I put it outside, it says it's not defined...

Comment: My bad, made a typo there. The first line lives inside function 1 and calls function 2 passing the list to the function. The return is then the revised list.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. I can see from your example that the list gets passed back to func_1 for further action. If I don't need that, just need func_2 to have access to use the list created in func_1, can I simply leave off the final return line?

Comment: Quite correct, my fault again, getting my languages mixed up. Added a full working example to the code. I think this should be exactly the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks again! Your example works perfectly, but when I put it into practice on my main app, with the 'def f1(myList)' line, I still get the 'f1(myList) takes no arguments, 1 given' error. Any ideas why that would be..?

Comment: Could be a naming issue with the parameter for your function. Try changing from 'def f1(myList)' to 'def f1(mlist)'. Python can get confused when when the variable being passed in is the same as the parameter. Apart from that, make sure the parameter is present in the function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Lists in python are always passed by reference, as they are mutable. What you need to do is create the list in the scope that calls both functions that need it and pass it in as a parameter

```
def f1(x, mlist):
    mlist.append(x)

def f2(x, y, mlist):
    if y in mlist:
        return mlist.pop(y+'.'+x)

my_list = []
f1('a') # my_list -> ['a']
f1('b') # my_list -> ['a', 'b']
f1('a.1') # mylist -> ['a', 'b', 'a.1']
f2('1', 'b') # returns nothing, does not modify list
f2('1', 'a') #return 'a.1', and mylist -> ['a', 'b']
```

Alternatively, just make the list a global variable